# Merging two 'tables' (function outputs) 1 to 1

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have two functions. We'll represent them as tables: order_items, order_details.

```
CREATE TABLE order_items
    ("order_item_id" int, "product_id" int, "quantity" int)
;

INSERT INTO order_items
    ("order_item_id", "product_id", "quantity")
VALUES
    (10, 1, 1),
    (11, 1, 1),
    (12, 1, 1),
    (13, 2, 2)
;

CREATE TABLE order_details
    ("order_details" jsonb, "product_id" int, "quantity" int)
;

INSERT INTO order_details
    ("order_details", "product_id", "quantity")
VALUES
    ('{"1":2,"2":5}'::jsonb, 1, 1),
    ('{"1":2,"2":6}'::jsonb, 1, 1),
    ('{"1":1,"2":4}'::jsonb, 1, 1),
    ('{"1":1,"2":4}'::jsonb, 2, 2)
;
```

I would like to take their outputs and have an output that looks like this:

```
("order_details", "product_id", "quantity", "order_item_id")
('{"1":2,"2":5}'::jsonb, 1, 1, 10),
('{"1":2,"2":6}'::jsonb, 1, 1, 11),
('{"1":1,"2":4}'::jsonb, 1, 1, 12),
('{"1":1,"2":4}'::jsonb, 2, 2, 13)
```

Basically, `order_details` can be associated with any `order_item_id` as long as the `product_id` and `quantity` match. The output must return 4 rows.

I've been trying to do this in plain SQL, but I am starting to feel like it's not possible. Using plpgsql is fine, but I figure there is a faster way than doing a double nested for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign a unique index in both tables, then use that for the join:

```
SELECT order_details, product_id, quantity, order_item_id
FROM (SELECT order_item_id, product_id, quantity,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, quantity) AS indx
      FROM order_items) AS items
JOIN (SELECT order_details, product_id, quantity,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, quantity) AS indx
      FROM order_details) AS details
USING (product_id, quantity, indx);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This doesn't work when there are only 2 options for matching, only 1 or >3.**

I was able to solve the problem by using the SQL below. I am not sure if this the best solution, but it was the only one I could come up with.

```
SELECT order_item_id, product_id, quantity, order_details
    FROM (
        SELECT max(indx) over (partition by order_item_id) maxs, indexs.*
        FROM(
            SELECT
            order_item_id,
            order_items.product_id,
            order_items.quantity,
            order_details.order_details,
            row_number() over (partition by order_items.product_id, order_items.quantity, order_details.order_details) indx
            FROM order_items, order_details
            WHERE order_items.quantity = order_details.quantity AND order_items.product_id = order_details.product_id
            ) indexs
        ) maxIndexes
    WHERE maxs = indx;
```

The inter most SELECT will assign row numbers to the partition containing product_id, quantity, and order_details.

The next one up will find the maximum row numbers for the previous partition. For some reason if you pick the maximum number for the partition, you will get no conflicts. Not sure why, but with the cases I used, that's what happens.

The last SELECT will just pick the row with the maximum for the innermost partition.

Again, not sure if this is the best way to do it. Any other solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I am not going to award myself best answer if it's not.